# Need an explanation on the class and instance variable assignment

Tags: python, class

I have a small code snippet for the class and instance variable creation and assignment, but I see unexpected results in the instance variable values when ran the code.

I am using PyCharm installation with Python version 3.11.3 (tags/v3.11.3:f3909b8, Apr  4 2023, 23:49:59) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]

Below is the code snippet I am trying :

```
class ClassCounter:
    counter = 0
    def __init__(self):
        self.counter += 4
        type(self).counter += 100

o1 = ClassCounter()
print("Instance variable value : ", o1.counter, ", Class variable value : ", ClassCounter.counter)
o2 = ClassCounter()
print("Instance variable value : ", o2.counter, ", Class variable value : ", ClassCounter.counter)
print("Class variable value : ", ClassCounter().counter) # this is printing class's counter variable value
print("Class variable value : ", ClassCounter.counter)
```

Output I see :

```
Instance variable value :  4 , Class variable value :  100
Instance variable value :  104 , Class variable value :  200
Class variable value :  204
Class variable value :  300
```

Output I expected :

```
Instance variable value :  4 , Class variable value :  100
Instance variable value :  4 , Class variable value :  200
Class variable value :  300
Class variable value :  400
```

Reason why I am expecting the above output is :
I understand that there are two 'counter' variables created,

- one is class variable (common for all the instances and is incremented by 100 each time an object is created) and
- the other is instance variable (separate for each instance created and is initialized as +4)

Comment: No, the *class attribute* defines the value for all instances, so as soon as you initialize the class once (increasing the *class attribute* to 100), the next instance starts from `self.counter == 100` and adds 4, hence your output `Instance variable value :  104`.

Comment: *"the other is instance variable (... initialized as 4)"* That would be the case if `__init__` contained `self.counter = 4`. But your `self.counter += 4` behaves differently, like @user2390182's answer explains.

Answer (score 2):

It is all about attribute lookup. Python will try the instance first and the class second as a fallback.

When you do

```
self.counter += 4
# which  is the equivalent of
self.counter = self.counter + 4
```

the following happens:

- The right hand side is evaluated:

  - The instance `self` has no attribute `counter`, so the class attribute is read instead.
  - `4` is added
- The result is stored as an attribute `counter` **on the instance**
- The class attribute is unchanged

Now, if you change the class attribute (`type(self).counter += 100`), for the next instance, this process starts a new just with an added `100`.

Btw, `ClassCounter().counter` does **not** print the class attribute. `ClassCounter()` is just another instance.

Comment: Thank you @user2390182. I have confirmed that the same would apply i.e. an instance variable is created when class variable is accessed as self.counter from anywhere in the methods in the same class and is initialized with a value same as class variable when self.counter is executed.